# is there a way to send a message after a message has been deleted?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So, when a user sends a message I want my bot to send a message to that channel with an emoji

so far I've been able to send it to a specific channel, but after that I haven't been able to send a message to any channel that a message was deleted in.

maybe I just don't know the attributes.

thanks for all the help in advance!

```
@bot.event
async def on_message_delete(ctx):
    if ctx.author.id != 835676293625282601:
        author = ctx.message.author
        del_msg = await channel.send(":eyes:")
        await author.send(del_msg)
        await asynciaito.sleep(10)
        await del_msg.delete()
```

Comment: Might be a good idea to mention this is for a discord bot in the description or title of the questions. Not everyone will look at the tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Events never take `ctx` as an argument, if you take a look at the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_message_delete) you can see that `on_message_delete` takes `message` as the only argument

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message_delete(message):
    if message.author.id != 835676293625282601:
        author = message.author
        del_msg = await message.channel.send(":eyes:")
        await author.send(del_msg)
        await asynciaito.sleep(10)
        await del_msg.delete()
```

Also you don't have to learn all the attributes from all the discord objects, just read the documentation

Comment: Thank you! I'm still really new to all of this. So thanks for the help!